# PHPMyAdmin shows blank screen after logging in

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, centos, cpanel

Since moving to a new VPS - we have been having issues accessing PHPMyAdmin. We have 15 websites (and cPanel accounts) hosted on this new VPS and PHPMyAdmin only works in two of the cPanels.

No errors show up on the rest, apart from the fact that it prompts a login screen. After entering login credentials - it takes us to a blank white screen. No errors show.

However, when in cPanel and clicking on MySQL Databases, the following error shows:

```
Error while connecting to MySQL: Cpanel::DBI::Mysql connect('','root',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/MysqlUtils/Connect.pm line 136 Error while connecting to MySQL: Cpanel::DBI::Mysql connect('','root',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/MysqlUtils/Connect.pm line 136 ...caught
```

It also says that the MySQL server is offline. It isn't though as all websites are working perfectly fine on the front end.

If you could suggest how to get PHPMyAdmin working again - then that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues myself with phpmyadmin but I clear the tmp folder and it would fix it.

Try running this and see if it does anything

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the phpMyAdmin and the cPanel credentials become out of sync.

Resetting the cPanel account password can fix this.

You may need to log out of cPanel and log back in again before the issue is fixed.